# Uncaught Highcharts error #19: www.highcharts.com/errors/19

Tags: highcharts, google-analytics, coffeescript

Recently I have implemented the highcharts in my application where I got perfect
view as displaying the Google analytics data but sometimes I am getting the below error,

Uncaught Highcharts error #19: www.highcharts.com/errors/19

Is there any one have idea about it?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: It is too many ticks, so you can use tickInterval, how your chart / data looks like

Answer (score 3):

### Highcharts Error #19

#### Too many ticks

This error happens when you try to apply too many ticks to an axis, specifically when you add more ticks than the axis pixel length. In practice, it doesn't make sense to add ticks so densely that they can't be distinguished from each other. One cause of the error may be that you set a tickInterval that is too small for the data value range. In general, tickPixelInterval is a better option, as it will handle this automatically. Another case is if you try to set categories on a datetime axis, which will result in Highcharts trying to add one tick on every millisecond since 1970.